# Tar multiple files in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, tar, parameter-expansion

I have this loop which loops through directories and looks for specific files ($path is read from script prompt):

```
for FILE in $path/*/logs/*2016-*; do 
######note that I don't have quotes around $path/*/logs/*2016-* in order for parameter expansion to work

  JOB=${FILE%/*/*}   
  JOB_NAME=${JOB##*/}

  cd $path/$JOB_NAME/logs
  tar zcvf 2016_logs.tgz "$FILE"
done
```

What is happening is it compresses each file and overrides tar file with each loop so I only get one file in my tar archive.

I need a single tgz file in $path/*/logs, with all the files that matched "2016-" in that directory

UPDATE:
I was able to fix my issue using this code:

```
for DIR in $path/*/logs ; do
    cd $DIR

    FILES=$(find ./ -type f -name "*${year}*" -print)
    if [[ -n $FILES ]];then
        tar -cvzf "${year}_logs.tgz" ${FILES}
    fi
done
else
  echo "file not found"
fi
```

Comment: what is `year`?

Comment: @kvantour sorry edited. I call $year later in my if statement

Comment: The name of your tar file (year) needs to be unique with every loop

Comment: @RamanSailopal I simplified this by removing $year totally. This was not the issue

Comment: Can you state wheat is the desired output. It looks as if you would like a single tgz file in $path/*/logs, with all the files that matched "*2016-*". Is this correct ?

Comment: @dash-o yes thats correct. Sorry i didnt make it cleared. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

The current code loops over FILES, and then it places a TGZ version of the file into 2016_logs.tgz in the same folder. It will be more effective to loop over the FOLDERS, and build each TGZ file from the individual data files.

Bash solution (shopt)

```
shopt -s nullglob
for DIR in $path/*/logs ; do
    files=$(shopt -s nullglob ; cd $DIR && echo *2016-*)
    [ "$files" ] || continue
    (cd $DIR && tar cvzf 2016_logs.tgz $files)
done
```

Comment: This sort of works thank you but it also creates empty 2016_logs.tgz in directories where 2016* files are not present

Comment: @user3508766 solution revised to handle folders with no matching files

Comment: Nothing happens. echo $files has no output

Comment: @user3508766 file lookup modified to use correct $DIR)